# How to resize matplotlib figure without changing the way it has been plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I have a figure with three subplots. If I plot it a the default width everything looks fine, but that is too big for my needs. So I want to resize the plot, but if I do that, the proportions of the text to the axis and the ticks change in a way that makes it unreadable, because labels and ticks run over each other.

I have tried to use smaller font sizes, but it doesn't yield the required results.

Is there a way to resize the image after the subplots have been plotted (so without changing anything to the way they are plotted)?

Here's the code

```
# Size with good result
fig = plt.figure(figsize=plt.figaspect(0.333))

# Size with bad result
# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4.77, 1.59))

f_msat = 6000000 #sensitivity in msat
f_sat = f_msat / 1000 #sensitivity in sat
f1 = f_sat / 3 # sensitivity 2000
f2 = 2 * f_sat / 3 # sensitivity 4000
f3 = f_sat

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 1, projection='3d')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 2, projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1, 3, 3, projection='3d')

capacity = np.arange(1000000, ((2**24-1))/2, 10000)

def capacity_plot(ax, c, f):
    e = np.arange(round(4*f*(n+t)/(2**24-1),2), 0.50, 0.01)
    E, C = np.meshgrid(e, c)
    i = np.where(C >= 2*f*(n+t)/E, 1 - ((f)/(C*E)), np.NaN)
    ax.set_title(r'$\Delta f='+ str(int(f)) +'$')
    ax.set_zlim(0.997,1)
    ax.set_xlim(0,0.5)
    ax.plot_surface(E, C, i)
    ax.set_xlabel('$\epsilon$')
    ax.set_ylabel('cap.')
    ax.set_zlabel('CIC',rotation=90)
    ax.yaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 1.0
    ax.xaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 1.0
    ax.zaxis._axinfo['label']['space_factor'] = 1.0

capacity_plot(ax1, capacity, f1)
capacity_plot(ax2, capacity, f2)
capacity_plot(ax3, capacity, f3)

fig.savefig('../paper/images/channel-information-coefficient.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
```

Big image:
[image: Image too large, but labels and ticks are well positioned]

Small image:
[image: Image size correct, but labels and ticks run over each other and]

Comment: [`.savefig()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.savefig.html) has the `dpi` option. You can decrease the value for png files but not for postscript or pdf outputs. DPI is imho ignored because the final application will resize and generate the displayed image. So, why would you need to decrease the figure size with this file format when this should be achieved in the final application, e.g., the embedding Word/LaTeX/whatever document?

Comment: @Mr.T I thought I *had* to achieve it with the figure size, because the figure itself is being referenced in Markdown (which is then compiled to LaTeX using Pandoc) but your comment put me on the right track: You can specify width and height in markdown like so: `![Channel Information Coefficient](paper/images/channel-information-coefficient.pdf){#fig:cic width=4.77inch height=1.59inch}` 
That works. You want to make your comment a proper answer, so that I can gift you the reputation of a accepted answer?

Comment: You are allowed and encouraged to write and accept your own answer. Maybe you can include in the question the detail that it is finally a LaTeX document?